# What is exactly executed when the Volume Up/Down/Mute keys are tapped?

Tags: sound, notification, volume-control, notify-osd

What is exactly executed when the `Volume Up/Down/Mute` keys are tapped?

I known that the system volume can be changed in a variety of ways (pactl, amixer...), however, I see that what Ubuntu does when the user taps volume keys is different - for example, it shows a notification, and has limiting once a limit is reached.

What is it?

My desktop environment is MATE.